# Godot KinematicBody2D Invisible After If Statement

Tags: collision-detection, godot, collider

The reason I address this question  is because of the limited documentation and support for starting devs on Godot. I do not know what is wrong with this one if statement, but after I added it, my player was unusable and invisible.

```
var collision = move_and_collide(vel * delta)

if collision.collider.name == "Spikes Tilemap":
    print("collided")
```

Spikes Tilemap is a tilemap I set custom to collision detection for spikes.

If you need more information, ask me. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Well, the if statement doesn't seem to do any harm... are you sure you didn't change anything else?

Comment: @ArianKeshvari I turned the if statement, and the if statement only, into a comment, and it ran just fine.

Comment: Do you see any error messages getting printed out? Can you share more of the script than the 3 lines you have so far? What script is that? The player? Is it a KinematicBody2D?

Comment: @yoozer8 It is a kinematic body 2d. the error is "Invalid get index 'collider' (on base: 'null instance')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the limited information you've provided, my guess is a null pointer exception in the script.

---

From the [KinematicBody2D docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html?highlight=kinematicbody2d#class-kinematicbody2d-method-move-and-collide) (assuming your player, and/or the script your showing us, is a KinematicBody2D):

> The body will stop if it collides. Returns a KinematicCollision2D, which contains information about the collision when stopped, or when touching another body along the motion.

From the [KinematicCollision2D docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_kinematiccollision2d.html#class-kinematiccollision2d) (discussing `move_and_collide` results):

> If a collision is detected, a KinematicCollision2D object is returned.

It seems `move_and_collide` doesn't always return a value, and will only actually give you an object if there is a collision. You should add a check that you actually got an object before trying to access that object's properties. If you got no result, assume there is no collision.

---

Based on your comment providing the error output, this is exactly the issue.

> It is a kinematic body 2d. the error is "Invalid get index 'collider' (on base: 'null instance')

The `move_and_collide` function only returns an object when there is a collision. Otherwise it returns null. It is called every frame, and there is not always a collision. You need to add a null check to verify it actually returned something before checking what kind of collision it was.

---

To <strike>fix</strike> avoid this particular error, change your if condition to the following, in order to make sure you only attempt to access properties on the collision object if it actually exists.

```
if collision != null:
    if collision.collider.name == "Spikes Tilemap":
        print("collided")

    # any other code that relies on using collision
```

Comment: I did have a node called spikes tilemap

Comment: I added a second spike on my tileset that has tilemap but it did nothing

Comment: @Athsmooth the `"Spikes Tilemap"` bit actually doesn't matter here (at least not for this particular bug). The problem is that you are trying to access the property of something that does not exist. Since no collision happens, `move_and_collide` returns null, so your variable `collision` doesn't actually have a value. So `collision.collider` fails, because `collision` is not an object with a property called `collider` (because it is not any object at all).

Comment: @Athsmooth I've added an example for how you can resolve this error. Hopefully that will help you

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems like I didn't fully understand what you were saying at the time. This does seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Athsmooth if this solved your problem, please consider marking this as the accepted answer (by clicking the green checkmark next to it)

Comment: Im so sorry! I forgot to check it!